# Strange error in SpringMVC Application Startup

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm getting a very strange stack trace when trying to load a SpringMVC application and at a lost to why this is occurring.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:996)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4834)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5155)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 35 more

Comment: Post your Spring XML configs. Also, turn on GC logging and post GC logs so that we can tell what type of OOM this is.

Comment: @jtoberon - the OOME exception *message* says it is a regular "Java heap space" OOME; i.e. increase heap space and try again.

Comment: The GC logs might tell us something, e.g. has the Xmx VM parameter been set properly.

Comment: The Xmx property is being set correctly (same as previous branch). The problem doesn't seem to be the configuration as I can start it if I manually deploy the war file. The problem only seems to occur when deploying through eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Its an Out of Memory Error - your JVM has run out of heap space initializing the webapp. Generally Spring takes care of cyclical references but pasting your bean config XML would help as well - like which scopes you're using, autowiring vs. not, etc.

You might want to increase the heap size using `-Xmx` VM parameter.

Comment: Per my other comment, this only occurs when deploying through eclipse.

Comment: Please use this link to increase heap space for Eclipse : http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a cyclical reference that just kept on trying to wire up until it exhausted your JVM, you'll need to post your spring file for more help

Comment: if Sprint was getting into a knot due to the cyclic reference, you'd most likely get a `StackOverflowError` (not TM :-) ).